# How to prevent CHKDSK from running upon boot

Tags: windows, boot, chkdsk

I have a digital signage screen that's running XPe (Windows XP Embedded).
I was having a few problems with it and so decided to run a CHKDSK on it to see if it could pick up on any errors. As per, it told me that it is unable to do so now and asked if I'd like to have it run upon next startup - to which I said yes.

Now, whenever the screen boots, it begins to launch XPe and then goes into CHKDSK. It runs all three checks quite quickly, goes black and begins the cycle again starting at beginning to boot XPe.

The on-screen countdown to cancel CHKDSK is interruptible (so it seems). I've also tried inserting a Windows boot drive into the screen and launching CMD from it. From there, I've run;

```
chkntfs x/ C:
```

but to no avail.

Is there something I'm missing?

Hopefully someone can help,

Thanks!

Comment: Do `chkdsk /f/r`.

Comment: Have just tried doing that. It went through and tried fixing the drives, though it still hasn't helped.

Comment: Replace the drive.

Comment: Replacing the drive isn't a great resolve, rather, just side-stepping the issue. Firstly, these are old, temperamental and sensitive digital signage screens - replacing any part of them is basically a no-go haha! Secondly, the OS is running from the RAM, which makes everything oh the more trickier....

Comment: Replacing a defective hardware is side-stepping? Are you expecting a magical software to correct bad sectors? There's no such thing.

Comment: I'm not expecting "magical software" to just fix it haha but it had no problems with booting until I decided to run a CHKDSK on it. In addition to that, it's only going into CHKDSK after Windows begins to load. Does that not imply that there's something in Windows telling it to run a CHKDSK each and every time it boots up?..

Comment: Yes, there is something telling Windows to run it. It detected problems that can't be corrected which means the drive is about to not work at all.